No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
I'm using spring and I've developed a service to generate pdf files, this is the controller:
@GetMapping(path = "/report/{taskProcessInstanceId}/pdf/{taskId}/tipo/{reportType}")
@ApiOperation(value = "service description TODO")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getReport(
      @PathVariable Integer taskId,
      @PathVariable BigDecimal taskProcessInstanceId,
      @PathVariable String reportType
      )
  throws JRException, IOException {

  try {
             
      String format = "pdf";
  
        byte[] reportContent = reportService.getItemReport(taskId, taskProcessInstanceId, format, reportType);
            
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"item-report." + format+"\"")
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(reportContent));

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) [..]

I can successfully generate and download a pdf, I tested it on Postman, but I keep seeing the following exception in console:
17:01:59,891 ERROR [stderr] (default task-57) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity["body"]->org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource["inputStream"])

I searched online and I can't understand the problem with my code. Why is it searching for a ByteArrayInputStream serializer?
thanks in advance.

In Spring Boot, add this to application.properties to disable FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS:
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false.

To disable FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS using the ObjectMapper directly:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

This tells Jackson not to throw an exception when it encounters an empty bean during serialization.

What I think is you should do this on a way that generate the PDF, store it in your local storage and return the link to download the file instead of directly returning the file stream as the response. Jackson is not able to parse the byte stream data as it has no specific data type. Even if you use the code spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false you will get null response.

Some thoughts:

If your program is doing what you want, but throwing an error message along the way, this isn't necessarily a problem. You can just ignore it.
Depending on your IDE(IntelliJ and Eclipse at least), you may be able to run it in debug mode and find out what specifically is going on.
Lastly, it seems to be asking for a BeanSerializer. You can always create one, perhaps in a config file, this would probably make the error go away.

